# Is it possible to get Source URL of iOS app

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, plugins

Can we get the source url which is used to install the application(inside app) programmatically in unity?

Is there any plugin available to do this ?

Let me explain, for example I'm showing some ads on your mobile, if you like or wished to install or visit that application. you will click the ad then you will be redirected to the respective store to install the application. So hereafter the developer of an application needed to track the source(advertiser) triggered this installation. for that if we can get the source url which is used to redirect and install, then by getting the parameters in the url we can track the advertiser.

Answer (score 0):

In AppStore , share the app and choose copy link. It will contains the app description and at the end the URL of the app in the AppStore

Comment: i need to get inside the application programmatically.